# Animation breaking on rapid button click

Tags: jquery

So i have a slider (which is very buggy a WIP) but if i was to hammer (a british term for spam) one of the two navigational buttons the slider seems to breaks.

I think the example should speak for itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/aZkPZ/

Comment: works fine on my machine

Comment: Wait! All that code to create a simple slider (that even goes out-of-viewport?)?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the navigational buttons like 20 times, do you notice each pane is supposed to animate about 789px, but if you press the button fast it does not animate the full course of the 789px

Comment: the intention is to make it dynamic :|

Comment: And...not to be rude... 98% of world wide sliders act OPPOSITE. right button = slide left. (view images on the right!) Just a suggestion. Think about the users

Comment: @roXon do you want to go to chat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4002/discussion-between-xavier-and-roxon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very clean and simple approach would be to disable the buttons for the duration of the animation. That way users can't "hammer" it. :)

Comment: Exactly, in addition to the animation, disable the button for the duration of the animation, and then re-enable it once the animation ends, that way you can only press it once per animation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/aZkPZ/2/ a simple `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` should of done the trick but it seems not! i have only attached the disable code to ensure it disabled the button, but then again im probably doing it wrong :D

Comment: By "disabling" I mean to cause the script not to work. I doesn't necessarily mean to add "disabled" to the button.